# Como sumar la propiedad total de varias instancias de muchas colecciones Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

quisiera pedirles un consejo para poder resolver esta pequeña duda que tengo,
tengo un colección estructurada de la siguiente manera

```
[
  [            <------ Este colección pertenece a un vendedor
   {           <------- Esta instancia pertenece a una venta realizada por el vendedor
    total:500,
    user_id:1
   },
   { 
    total:1500,
    user_id:1
   }
  ],
  [
   {
    total:100,
    user_id:3
   },
   {
   total:200,
   use_id:3
   }
  ]
]
```

en donde tengo crear una nueva colección con su respectiva instancia sumando el total de ventas realizadas a lo largo de la semana quedando de la siguiente manera

```
 [
  [            <------ Este colección pertenece a un vendedor
   {           <------- Esta instancia es la suma de todos las instancias pertenecientes al vendedor
    totalVentasSemanal:2000,
    user_id:1
   }
  ],
  [
   {
    totalVentasSemanal:300,
    user_id:3
   }
  ]
]
```

Cual seria la forma correcta de lograr este resultado, tengo mi consulta hecha, y he sumado el total de cada objeto dentro de un foreach pero no logro hacerlo funcionar , si me pudieran dar un consejo de como resolverlo se los agradecería mucho.

Esta es mi consulta hasta el momento

```
$weeklySales = User::with(['sales'=>function($query){
            
            $WeekStart = Carbon::parse("last monday")->startOfDay();
            $WeekEnd   = Carbon::parse("saturday")->endOfDay();

            $formatWeekStart = $WeekStart->toDateTimeString();
            $formatWeekEnd = $WeekEnd->toDateTimeString();


            $arraySales = $query->whereBetween('sales.created_at',[$formatWeekStart , $formatWeekEnd]);

        }])->where('users.type_user',2)->get()->pluck('sales');


         $suma = 0;

         foreach ($weeklySales as $sales) {
       
             $suma += $sales[0]->total;  
         }
        }
```

[image: array]

Comment: Esta consulta que resultado da?

Comment: me retorna la suma de las instancias , pero solo del primera colección

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que:

- Debes hacer una sumatoria de las ventas semanales dentro de la función accediendo a *total* por medio de la relación `sales`
- Posterior agrupar en este caso por la llave foránea que guardan `sales` y que es el id del cliente con el cual están vinculadas

Opcionalmente:

- Considera no sobrecargar la función de la consulta
- Puedes mover las variables con las cuales obtienes el último lunes ocurrido y el sábado fuera de la función y solo pasarlas como argumentos de la misma
- Eliminé a `$arraySales` al menos con el código expuesto no parece tener mayor relevancia o importancia de que exista declarada en tu código

Consulta:

```
$WeekStart = Carbon::parse("last monday")->startOfDay();
$WeekEnd   = Carbon::parse("saturday")->endOfDay();

$formatWeekStart = $WeekStart->toDateTimeString();
$formatWeekEnd   = $WeekEnd->toDateTimeString();

$weeklySales = User::with(['sales' => function($query) use ($formatWeekStart, $formatWeekEnd){

    $query->selectRaw('user_id, SUM(total) AS totalVentasSemanal')
          ->whereBetween('sales.created_at',[$formatWeekStart , $formatWeekEnd])
          ->groupBy('user_id');

}])->whereTypeUser(2)->get();
```

**Extra**

Dado que en tus etiquetas indicas usar Laravel 6, puedes prescindir de usar directamente la clase `Carbon` y en su lugar usar el [helper `now()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-now) que crea una instancia de esta misma.

Mas o menos así:

```
$WeekStart = now()::parse("last monday")->startOfDay();
$WeekEnd   = now()::parse("saturday")->endOfDay();
```

Comment: BetaM muchísimas gracias el enfoque que le estaba dando era erróneo, lo que note es que si me hace la suma en la primera colección pero en la segunda la manda vacía , me puede hacer una observación en esa parte?

Comment: lo que pasa es que tengo solo 2 vendedores , ambos vendedores tiene almenos 2 ventas registradas de momento , correspondiente a los rangos de fechas que declaro con Carbon, ahí es en donde no logro entender porque en la primera colección si hace la suma y en la segunda no, tomando en cuenta que ese vendedor si tiene ventas realizadas

Comment: muestra el arreglo sales de la segunda colección vacío , pero al verificar la consulta sin el selectRow me trae las ventas realizadas de los dos usuarios(Agregue una pequela imagen con el arreglo que se muestra actualmente)

Comment: @RodrigoA.Moreno revisa por favor la última edición que realicé

Comment: si ya funciono, no se me hubiera ocurrido que se solucionaría con un groupBy, muchísimas gracias me ayudaste mucho.